# Any example where client certification is required?

Tags: tls

There are some optional cases in SSL/TLS where server can demand the certificate of the client. Can anyone give me any example regarding this?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe startssl does this to authenticate its users

Comment: @tangrs - Yes.  If you go to https://www.startssl.com and try to create a free SSL certificate (e.g., for your website), they'll require you to first generate a SSL certificate for client authentication (to login) with startssl.com instead of a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An SSL server requires a client certificate *if the server says so*. In an overall system, this makes sense only if authorized clients have been provisioned with certificates, which is not a very common situation.

In my daily work, we develop and deploy a [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) for distributing smart cards, and certificates on smart cards, to physicians. This is so that the said physicians may access from their computers centralized medical records for patients. Medical records are "very private" and thus strong authentication is needed for access; when using Web-based technology (the tool on the physician side of things is a Web browser), the authentication is based on SSL and the SSL server demands a certificate from the client.

PKI is complex (the software is simple, the *procedures* are mindbogglingly twisted and byzantine) so such things happen only when someone injects a lot of money in the project.

Some banks have played with the concept of issuing certificates to their customers -- for Web authentication (in SSL) and, more importantly, for *digital signatures* on bank order submitted online (this kind of signature is not an SSL feature). I think UBS was doing that at some point; I am not sure they still do.